# Implement Columns.Columns property in custom Delphi component

Tags: delphi

I'm doing a conversion of several Delphi 2005 apps to XE2 and they use a component that no longer is available, so I've written my own custom component to handle the basics, which is generally OK when you drop the component onto a form, however I ran into a problem when I open a VCL form containing this component that has properties already set in the DFM.

Delphi 2005 DFM contains something like this:

```
  object ExtendedGrid1: TExtendedGrid
    Left = 32
    Top = 16
    Width = 577
    Height = 257
    TabOrder = 0
    Columns.Columns = (
      'OE6.02'
      (
        'Test1'
        64
        False
        0
        'clWindowText'
        -11
        'Tahoma'
        0
        8
        False
        False
        False
        False
        0
        1
        0
        0
        0
        1
        0
        'clWindowText'
        -11
        'Tahoma'
        0
        8
        False
        False
        False
        False
        0
        1
        0
        'test2'
        64
        False
        0
        'clWindowText'
        -11
        'Trebuchet MS'
        0
        8
        True
        True
        False
        False
        0
        1
        0
        0
        0
        1
        0
        'clWindowText'
        -11
        'Tahoma'
        0
        8
        False
        False
        False
        False
        0
        1
        0
        ''
        '0'))
    RowHeights = (
      19
      19)
  end
```

Even though my component has a Columns property based on a class inheriting from TCollection, and I've added a Columns property to the collection which uses the inherited Items, I get this error when I try and open the form in the designer:

Error creating form: Error reading MyGrid1.Columns.Columns: Property Columns does not exist.

If I create a new copy of my component, then set the columns up, I see something completely different in the DFM:

```
Columns = <
  item
    Title = 'Test1'
    Width = 64
    Editable = False
    HeaderClipStyle = csClip
    HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
    HeaderFont.Height = -11
    HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    HeaderFont.Style = []
    HeaderHAlign = haRight
    HeaderInnerBevel = bvNone
    HeaderOuterBevel = bvNone
    HeaderBorderWidth = 0
    HeaderBevelWidth = 0
    ContentsClipStyle = csClip
    ContentsFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    ContentsFont.Color = clWindowText
    ContentsFont.Height = -11
    ContentsFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    ContentsFont.Style = []
    ComboFilled = False
    ComboEditable = False
  end
  item
    Title = 'test2'
    Width = 64
    Editable = False
    HeaderClipStyle = csClip
    HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
    HeaderFont.Height = -11
    HeaderFont.Name = 'Trebuchet MS'
    HeaderFont.Style = []
    HeaderInnerBevel = bvNone
    HeaderOuterBevel = bvNone
    HeaderBorderWidth = 0
    HeaderBevelWidth = 0
    ContentsClipStyle = csClip
    ContentsFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    ContentsFont.Color = clWindowText
    ContentsFont.Height = -11
    ContentsFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    ContentsFont.Style = []
    ComboFilled = False
    ComboEditable = False
  end
  end>
```

Can anyone point me to some articles or explanations that will allow me to write my custom component so it can handle the old Delphi 2005 DFM's? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that you are going to need to use WriteListBegin/WriteListEnd and ReadListBegin/ReadListEnd. Have a look at how the RowHeights and ColWidths properties are handled in TCustomGrid. Look at TCustomGrid.DefineProperties.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer but it might get you started (you need to add all the required properties to `TColumn` and implement their reading/writing in `ReadColumn`/`WriteColumn` methods):

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Contnrs;

type
  TColumn = class
  private
    FName: string;
    FWidth: Integer;
  public
    property Name: string read FName;
    property Width: Integer read FWidth;
  end;

  TColumns = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FItems: TObjectList;
    FOwner: TComponent;
    function GetCount: Integer;
    function GetItems(Index: Integer): TColumn;
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
    function GetOwner: TPersistent; override;
    function ReadColumn(Reader: TReader): TColumn;
    procedure ReadColumns(Reader: TReader);
    procedure WriteColumn(Writer: TWriter; Column: TColumn);
    procedure WriteColumns(Writer: TWriter);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    property Count: Integer read GetCount;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TColumn read GetItems; default;
  end;

  TTestComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FColumns: TColumns;
    procedure AddTestColumns;
    procedure SetColumns(Value: TColumns);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Columns: TColumns read FColumns write SetColumns;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Test', [TTestComponent]);
end;

{ TColumns }

function TColumns.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FItems.Count;
end;

function TColumns.GetItems(Index: Integer): TColumn;
begin
  Result := TColumn(FItems[Index]);
end;

function TColumns.GetOwner: TPersistent;
begin
  Result := FOwner;
end;

procedure TColumns.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited DefineProperties(Filer);
  Filer.DefineProperty('Columns', ReadColumns, WriteColumns, Count > 0);
end;

function TColumns.ReadColumn(Reader: TReader): TColumn;
begin
  Result := TColumn.Create;
  try
    Result.FName := Reader.ReadString;
    Result.FWidth := Reader.ReadInteger;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TColumns.ReadColumns(Reader: TReader);
var
  Version: string;
begin
  Reader.ReadListBegin;
  Version := Reader.ReadString;
  if Version = 'OE6.02' then
  begin
    Reader.ReadListBegin;
    FItems.Clear;
    while not Reader.EndOfList do
      FItems.Add(ReadColumn(Reader));
    Reader.ReadListEnd;
  end;
  Reader.ReadListEnd;
end;

procedure TColumns.WriteColumn(Writer: TWriter; Column: TColumn);
begin
  Writer.WriteString(Column.FName);
  Writer.WriteInteger(Column.FWidth);
end;

procedure TColumns.WriteColumns(Writer: TWriter);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Writer.WriteListBegin;
  Writer.WriteString('OE6.02');
  Writer.WriteListBegin;
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
    WriteColumn(Writer, Items[I]);
  Writer.WriteListEnd;
  Writer.WriteListEnd;
end;

constructor TColumns.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FOwner := AOwner;
  FItems := TObjectList.Create;
end;

destructor TColumns.Destroy;
begin
  FItems.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TColumns.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  Column: TColumn;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Source is TColumns then
  begin
    FItems.Clear;
    for I := 0 to TColumns(Source).Count - 1 do
    begin
      Column := TColumn.Create;
      try
        Column.FName := TColumns(Source)[I].FName;
        Column.FWidth := TColumns(Source)[I].FWidth;
        FItems.Add(Column);
      except
        Column.Free;
        raise;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

{ TTestComponent }

procedure TTestComponent.AddTestColumns;
  procedure AddColumn(const AName: string; AWidth: Integer);
  var
    Column: TColumn;
  begin
    Column := TColumn.Create;
    try
      Column.FName := AName;
      Column.FWidth := AWidth;
      FColumns.FItems.Add(Column);
    except
      Column.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  end;
begin
  AddColumn('Test1', 64);
  AddColumn('Test2', 128);
end;

procedure TTestComponent.SetColumns(Value: TColumns);
begin
  FColumns.Assign(Value);
end;

constructor TTestComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FColumns := TColumns.Create(Self);
  AddTestColumns;
end;

destructor TTestComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FColumns.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

end.
```

This code produces the following result in the .dfm:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 282
  ClientWidth = 418
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object TestComponent1: TTestComponent
    Columns.Columns = (
      'OE6.02'
      (
        'Test1'
        64
        'Test2'
        128))
    Left = 200
    Top = 144
  end
end
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully for being able to read the columns property information from an old Delphi 2005 form. However, whereas I originally used a TCollection and TCollectionItem, which automatically included a collection property editor for the component, the new implementation does not allow me to alter individual column object properties through the designer. The Columns property no longer has the ... button when I view the grid in the Object Inspector. Do I need to write my own property editor?